# Mysql запрос, ошибка

Tags: php, mysql

```
$strSql = "INSERT INTO it_catalog_rmenu_index (ID, SECTION, LOGO, PRICE, ANONS_MENU, ACTIVE, NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, METRO, METRO_ID, TYPE, KITCHEN, DELIVERY_CONDITION, COUNTRY, CITY_ID, TYPE_ID, KITCHEN_ID, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, PREVIEW_PICTURE, DETAIL_PAGE_URL)
                    VALUES (".$arItemsMenu['FIELDS']['ID'], $arItemsMenu['FIELDS']['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'], CFile::GetPath($arInfoRestorans['FIELDS']['PREVIEW_PICTURE']), $ar_res['PRICES']['1']['PRICE'], $arItemsMenu['FIELDS']['PREVIEW_TEXT'], 1, $arItemsMenu['FIELDS']['NAME'], $arInfoRestorans['PROP']['ADDRESS']['VALUE'], $arInfoRestorans['PROP']['CITYTXT']['VALUE'], $arRestMetro['NAME'], $arInfoRestorans['PROP']['METRO']['VALUE'],
                    $arInfoRestorans['PROP']['TYPE']['VALUE'], implode($arInfoRestorans['PROP']['KITCHEN']['VALUE']), $arInfoRestorans['PROP']['DELIVERY_CONDITION']['VALUE'], $arInfoRestorans['PROP']['CITY']['VALUE'], $arInfoRestorans['PROP']['VALUE_ENUM_ID']['VALUE'], implode($arInfoRestorans['PROP']['KITCHEN']['VALUE_ENUM_ID']), $arCoords[0], $arCoords[1],
                    CFile::GetPath($arItemsMenu['FIELDS']['PREVIEW_PICTURE']), $detailpage.")";
```

Наверно я что-то напутал и неправильно поставил/не поставил апострофы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про конкатенацию строк в ПХП .
Вы пытаетесь объединить строки при помощи запятой например здесь.

```
$arItemsMenu['FIELDS']['ID'], $arItemsMenu['FIELDS']['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'],
```

должно быть

```
$arItemsMenu['FIELDS']['ID'].", ".$arItemsMenu['FIELDS']['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'].", ".
```

Comment: Bitrix рулит )))